# SQL problems with UPDATE SET FROM WHERE statements

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm very bad at SQL so I'm struggling to UPDATE using values coming from separate tables:

I need use values inside 2 different tables as well as values from PHP script as part of an update query into a third table. with help I was able to make this statement but im getting syntax errors

ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from
order1
join supplier
on supplier.Order_ID = order1.order_ID
join pr' at line 6

My code is here:

```
 update order1
    set Reorder_Time=supplier.Reorder_Time,
        Amount_Ordered="123456789",
        Stock_Amount=product.Stock_Amount,
from order1
    join supplier on supplier.Order_ID = order1.order_ID 
    join production on supplier.Product_ID = product.Product_ID
where orderId = "123456789"
```

Comment: You are using sqlserver code in mysql. mysql multi table update is different see manual page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 1):

```
join production on supplier.Product_ID = product.Product_ID
```

In this line, write to `production.Product_Id` instead of `product.Product_ID`.

or you can use,

```
from  order1 o
    inner join supplier sp on sp.Order_ID = o.order_ID 
    inner join production p on sp.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
where orderId = "123456789"`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).